# Fitting an integral function given a set of data points

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have measures of the resistivity of a given material measured at different thickness and I have to fit those points using the Fuchs-Sondheimer model. I defined the fitting function in this way:

```
def ff(x, aa, p):
    return aa/(1-(3/(2*x))*integrate.quad(lambda t: (1/t**3 - 1/t**5)*(1-numpy.exp(-x*t))/(1-p*numpy.exp(-x*t)), 1, 1000))
```

where t is the integration variable, x is the thickness of the material, so it is the independent variable, while aa and p are two fitting parameters. When I run the code it gives me an error in the integral definition:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I suppose that the reason of the error is that x and p appear in the integral function as well as the integration variable t and so it says that I'm trying to pass a vector to the integral. Indeed if I try to eliminate x and p from the integral the code runs. 
How can I modify my code to make it work?

Comment: I guess `x` is an array. change the definition of `ff` such that you iterate yourself over the elements of `x`

Comment: How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def ff( x, aa ):
    return aa * quad( lambda t: t - x * t**2, 0, 1 )

def ff_select( x, aa ):
    return aa * quad(lambda t: t - x * t**2, 0, 1 )[0]

def ff_iter( x, aa ):
    if isinstance( x, (list, tuple, np.ndarray )):
        out = np.fromiter( ( ff_iter( y, aa ) for y in x ), np.float )
    else:
        out = aa * quad( lambda t: t - x * t**2, 0, 1 )[0]
    return out


print "this works, but is not desired"
print ff( 5 , 3 )

try:
    print ff( 5 , 3.1 )
except TypeError:
    print "\nquad returns a tuple. Select the result by picking the first element."

print "\nthis works"
print ff_select( 5 , 3.1 )
print "but still can't handle lists"
xx = np.linspace( 0, 1, 10 )
print
try:
    print ff_select( xx , 3 )
except TypeError:
    print "quad has problems with lists. Make the iteration external."

print"\nUsing this function definition should work in all reasonable cases"
print ff_iter( 5.1, 3.1 )
print ff_iter( xx, 3.1 )
print ff_iter( ( 1, 1.1, 2.1), 3.1 )
print ff_iter( [ 1, 1.1, 2.1 ], 3.1 )
## one may think about extending the code such that the output type 
## matches the input.Right now it is always an ndarray.
```